# Can Spring 3 formBackingObject return different command classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a situation where I need to check a condition in my formBackingObject and, depending on the condition, return one of two classes.

The problem is that, so far as I know, I can only define one commandName and commandClass in the servlet.xml. Anyone know of a way I can handle this? It doesn't seem like a rare use case, but I haven't really found any solution on the net.

Here is the logic block from my controller formBackingObject:

```
    List<FooLoadShed> fooLoadShedList = this.fooLoadShedDao.getActiveSheds();
    if(fooLoadShedList.isEmpty()) {
        logger.info("LoadShedActive is: " + this.sessionDetailsManager.getSessionDetails().isLoadShedActive());
        return new NoAction();
    }
    else {
        this.sessionDetailsManager.getSessionDetails().setLoadShedActive(true);
        logger.info("LoadShedActive is   : " + this.sessionDetailsManager.getSessionDetails().isLoadShedActive());
        logger.info("Number of load sheds: " + nieLoadShedList.size());
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("custLookup.htm"));
    }
```

and my servlet.xml config:

```
<bean name="/index.htm" class="springapp.web.indexController" scope="session">
    <property name="sessionForm" value="true"/>
    <property name="commandName" value="noAction"/>
    <property name="commandClass" value="springapp.service.NoAction"/>
    <property name="formView" value="index"/>
    <property name="sessionDetailsManager" ref="sessionDetailsManager"/>
    <property name="mobiConfigDao" ref="mobiConfigDao"/>
    <property name="fooLoadShedDao" ref="fooLoadShed" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very old way to configure controllers Spring MVC! Haven't seen something like this in over 10 years. Why not use more modern Spring MVC configuration, using annotations instead of XML?

In any case, the importance of the command class is in the POST. Spring MVC must be able to construct an instance of the command class. In order to do that, it needs to know the specific class name. Then it will apply the form values to the properties on the command class object that was created. This fully populated command object will be handed to you in the handler method.

The configuration in the XML is for the default command object creation process. You can override this. In modern Spring MVC, this is with a method level @ModelAttribute annotation. In ancient Spring MVC, you need to override the methods that create the command object and create the command object yourself. `BaseCommandController` has a `createCommand` method which is protected. If that's the way you created your controller, that's where you would have to start.